# trouble with a javascript Cannot read property 'value' of

Tags: javascript, getelementbyid

I've done a function but I do not understand why, a part of it does not work.

Actualy I use the methode using className and Id.

Here is the part of the code:

```
 var items = new Array();
 var itemCount = document.getElementsByClassName("items");

 for(var i = 0; i < itemCount.length; i++)
 {
     items[i] = document.getElementById("p"+(i+1)).value;
 }

 return items;
 }
```

And in jsfiddle the html part that show that this Id exist.

So it should not return to me this errors:

Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'value' of null fiddle.jshell.net:402

the concerned line is the following:

items[i] = document.getElementById("p"+(i+1)).value;

Comment: no error when i ran it.. which action should i do in page?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your fiddle, you have td element with id p7 missing and p8 two times. Is that only in your fiddle example or in your actual code as well? If it's in your code too, then there is your problem.
You have to correct one of those id's to p7.

Comment: this was the trouble I had a probelm on the databse that truncated the real value. Thank you so much for your observation

Answer (score 2):

It means that:

```
document.getElementById("p"+(i+1))
```

returns `null` in some loop iteration. In other words, the element does not exist. And then you try to retrieve the `.value` property from `null`, which throws an exception.

**Update**

If I read the code right, `p7` is missing. You can check that like this:

```
var elem = document.getElementById("p"+(i+1));
if ( !elem ) {
    alert('p'+(i+1)+' is missing!');
}
```

Comment: I know what it mean, but actualy as you can see on the fiddle this element exists

Comment: The fiddle is crazy, could you strip it down to the most essential?

Comment: all p+i are in the columns MONTANT RESTANT

Comment: That doesn’t help, I don’t even know how to call the function from the UI. If you want people to debug your code, you need to post more specific examples.

Comment: in the input where it is written MONTANT it launch the function, I've retired the less important thing

Comment: ya that's a right answer

Answer (score 1):

this happens for the last element, i+1.
so just change that.

```
for(var i = 0; i < itemCount.length; i++)
{
alert("i"+i+" "+document.getElementById("p" + (i+1)).value);
 items[i] = document.getElementById("p" + (i+1)).value;
 }
```

this runs untill the 5th element, ie p6.
As it's shown p7 is missing from server code itself.

Comment: Dear Sir, can you please explain to me how to do in order to see where does the code stop running?

Comment: as i alerted the value, a popup alert is shown in all the iterations, when p7 is missing, error is thrown.